# Post-Gzip contentLength in Tomcat Custom Valve

Tags: java, tomcat

In a custom Tomcat Valve is there any way to get the contentLength after the content has been gzipped?  response.getContentCountLong() returns the pre-gzipped size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GZIP, the total length of the compressed content is unpredictable beforehand. It's only known when the last bit has been compressed. In Tomcat, a GZIP response is usually directly sent in chunks (with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`) and never fully buffered in memory beforehand since this may be memory hogging. So I don't see ways to get the content length beforehand other than counting the bytes written to the outputstream yourself, or manually buffering the entire outputstream of the response and manually sending/flushing it fully on close (which may be memory hogging).

Comment: Thanks!  That is helpful.  I now have a Valve and a custom GzipOutputFilter which keeps track of how many bytes it has sent.  Then I manually flush it in my Valve.  Pretty messy but it works.  I think a better way might be to add an OutputFilter to the pipeline after the GzipOutputFilter and do the tracking in there.  Any ideas on how do add an OutputFilter?  Could I do that from a Listener?  Via JMX?